# gdalwarp to clip a .tif: Works fine standalone, won't work in Python

Tags: python, clip, gdalwarp

I am trying to use the subprocess module to call gdal warp and clip a .tif using a shapefile. When I try the command in GDAL it works fine, but when I attempt to call it into a Python script it will not work, and merely crashes. Below is the code I'm using:

```
import os, gdal, subprocess, sys
cmd = ['gdalwarp','-cutline','C:/IDStudy/Input/Clip.shp','-crop_to_cutline','-dstalpha','C:/IDStudy/Input/Merged.tif','C:/IDstudy/Output/Clipped.tif']
proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
stdout,stderr=proc.communicate()
exit_code=proc.wait()

if exit_code: #Oops, something went wrong!
    raise RuntimeError(stderr)
else: print stdout
```

This subprocess command works fine for merging/reprojecting but for some reason doesn't like to clip my raster...Any thoughts?

Comment: Where/how did you install gdalwarp, and how/where are you running your commands?

Comment: Any error message? Or crashes without error?

Comment: Try adding gdal.UseExceptions() and see if it will throw a message.

Answer (score 1):

I can't say I have a solution to the problem using subprocess as I had similar problems to what you describe before. In the end I decided to use os.system instead of subprocess (I am aware that subprocess is meant to replace os.system). So what I do is:

```
cmd = "gdalwarp ..." %(...)
os.system(cmd)
```